# RTD readout using wheatstone bridge and MCP6N11

Tags: wheatstone-bridge, rtd

For a project I require simple temperature sensing. The specifications are as follows:

- temperature range: 50-250 Celsius
- costs resonably low (< 10 US)
- accuracy +/- 2 degrees

for cost and availability reasons I selected the following RTD: ([farnell](http://nl.farnell.com/labfacility/dm-507/sensor-pt1000-thin-film-2x10mm/dp/7745655))

The trick now is to get the temperature information into a micro controller. This will be accomplished using an Wheatstone bridge and an MCP6N11 ([farnell](http://nl.farnell.com/microchip/mcp6n11-001e-sn/amp-instr-800ua-8soic/dp/2065857)). The gain of the amplifier has to be around 6. A proposed schematic can be found below (note that the RTD is placed between "R_uit" and "R_in").

[image: Proposed circuit design]

There rests only one question. How do I properly set Vref? Considering that the micro controller can measure between 0 and 5V, which I prefer to utilize fully. In the datasheet is stated that Vref "lifts" the output voltage. With that in mind, isn't it best to just ground Vref? It is provided that the MCP6N11 is a rail-to-rail device.

In the User guide of the demonstration board they talk about setting Vref around 1.8V when Vdd is 5V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V<sub>ref</sub> of an amplifier determines its zero point; when the input is 0, the output will be equal to V<sub>ref</sub>. If the polarity to be measured is equal in both directions then V<sub>ref</sub> should be 2.5V for maximum range with a 5V ADC, otherwise it should be biased appropriately given the input.

Comment: using the circuit and RTD described above, the potential difference is between 0 and +0.5V. Given that, polarity only has to be measured in one direction. So grounding it should not be an issue right?

Comment: Assuming rail-to-rail input and output. Otherwise keep it a few hundred millivolts within the linear range.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, grounding it should be okay, since you don't need to read down to 0°C. With offset and such like, you might not be able to distinguish 1-2°C from less than that.

Note that you'll get **significant** self-heating with such an arrangement, I would recommend no more than 10% of the current you are using and up the gain of the inamp proportionally.